# Ufw blocks incoming and outgoing connections

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, firewall, ufw

To update firewall rules, reloading ufw `ufw reload` blocking incoming and outgoing connections for around 2 seconds, untill it completes reload process.

I have set already the default policy deny for incoming and allow for outgoing.. ufw is enabled already.

Not sure why it blocks the connection. Is this a bug in kernel version 5.4.72?

Versions:

Ubuntu - 20.04.2 lts

ufw - 0.36

kernel - 5.4.72

Comment: My opinion. If I am updating my firewall to exclude some IP or port then we want that applied ASAP.  Right now. I don't want to wait for the rules to reload. Of course this is not possible so we have the default behavior of blocking *all* traffic. This is a precaution, favoring safety over efficiency. Since safety is the firewalls primary mission, this is acceptable. The actual spec might say something else, but this is how I think it should work.

Comment: So ufw rules are updating on the fly? it don't require `ufw reload` to update the new rule?

Comment: My guess is that the simplest way to update the rules table is to replace it rather than to selectively modify it. But like I said: I'm just guessing here, waiting for an expert on ufw / iptables to explain what's going on.

Comment: ufw is just a front end for iptables. Rules can be added or deleted for iptables on the fly.